# Using TOP and WHERE in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to use **TOP** and **WHERE** multiple times? similar as a for loop to create a table?

I am using the following query to create a table that contains the top 26 records where the value of the column [code] is 11:

```
SELECT TOP 26 [date]
  ,[group]
  ,[code]
  ,[pol]
  ,[relation]
FROM [database].[table1] WHERE group in ('A','B','C',...,'Z') and code = '11'
```

The problem with this query is that I get 26 records with the value of the column [group] equal to A. This happens because there are thousands of records that meet that criterion.

Ideally, I would like the top 1 of each group (A to Z) with the value of code 11. I could achieve that by running the query above 26 times using **TOP 1** and a different value of group, but this is impractical.

Is there any way to run this query multiple times to get the desired table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top n row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to assign a `ROW_NUMBER()`, then only return rows `WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = 1`. You may need to adjust the `PARTITION/ORDER BY` depending on your data and what you're expecting your result set to be.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [group], code ORDER BY code ASC) AS rn
   FROM table1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND code = 11
```

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MPh8-PRd).**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database support `WITH TIES`, then no need for a subquery. You can just `order by` with `row_number`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
   [date]
  ,[group]
  ,[code]
  ,[pol]
  ,[relation]
FROM [database].[table1]
WHERE group in ('A','B','C',...,'Z') and code = '11'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY [date] desc)
```

You did not tell which column should be used to identify the top row per group, so I used a descending sort on the date. For each group, `ROW_NUMBER` assigns `1` to  the row with the latest date ; `TOP 1 WITH TIES` then selects all such rows.